# file uploading in webview with form target to iframe?

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to avoid future back button problems with sending form in web view to with target to iframe but target attribute not working correctly in webview...

```
<form action="......." enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm" data-ajax="false" target="hiddenUploadIframe" method="POST">
...
</form>
<iframe id="hiddenUploadIframe" name="hiddenUploadIframe" style="width:0; height:0; border:0; border:none"></iframe>
```

ANY SUGESTION ?

Comment: after that I just want to 'window.parent.location.reload()'

Comment: is this in android app webview or is just web app frontend(browser)?

Comment: in chrome it was working but when I run it throught android webview it do not open in iframe

Comment: I do not wont to replace State in history with jquery if there is other possibility currently need to history.replaceState to aovid the back button go to upload page

Comment: @IAmBatman problem is in webview app I do not now if it support target attribute or not